# When I'm in post editor and click on 'Add media', why won't it load the media library with this code?

Tags: media-library

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {

    global $user_ID;

    if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) {
remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
 remove_menu_page('edit.php'); // posts? 
 remove_menu_page( 'profile.php'); // profile
 remove_menu_page('index.php');  
    remove_menu_page( 'post-new' ); 
    }
    remove_menu_page('users.php');
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    remove_menu_page('themes.php'); //appearance
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group' ); // advanced custom fields
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
}
```

I don't understand why it won't load the media library when I click on 'add media', whilst the above code is in functions.php. Please can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The correct hook to add/remove menus in admin area is [`admin_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu). Also, be aware that `current_user_can` is intented to check user capabilities, not user roles. See [current_user_can documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) and [notes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes).

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( ! empty( $user ) && in_array( "contributor", (array) $user->roles ) ) {

        remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
        remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
        remove_menu_page('edit.php'); // posts? 
        remove_menu_page( 'profile.php'); // profile
        remove_menu_page('index.php');  
        remove_menu_page( 'post-new' );

    }

    remove_menu_page('users.php');
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    remove_menu_page('themes.php'); //appearance
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );

}
```